# Vue checkbox not updating with data change

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

Having problems with my data in Vue updating the UI, but only checkboxes seem to have this problem.

I'm trying to allow only one checkbox to be checked at one time, therefore I'm setting all the checkboxes to false upon clicking one of them. However, this works in the data but isn't rendered correctly in the checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<table class="buildings-modify--table table-full table-spacing">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Primary</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>City/Town</th>
          <th>Province</th>
          <th>Postal Code</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Active</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr v-for="landlord in selectedLandlords" :key="landlord.id">
         <td>{{ landlord.name }}</td>
         <td>                            
           <input type="checkbox" :value="landlord.is_primary" @change.prevent="makePrimaryLandlord(landlord)">
         </td>
         <td>{{ landlord.address }}</td>
         <td>{{ landlord.city }}</td>
         <td>{{ landlord.province}}</td>
         <td>{{ landlord.postal_code}}</td>
         <td>{{ landlord.phone }}</td>
         <td>{{ landlord.is_active ? "Yes" : "No" }}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Vue Code:

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            selectedLandlords: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        makePrimaryLandlord: function(landlord) {
            this.selectedLandlords = this.selectedLandlords.map(item => {
                item.is_primary = false; return item});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only the checkbox appears to have an issue. If I change say the name, or a text value with a filtered array setting them all to a specific value they change but the checkboxes data change doesn't reflect in the UI, however the data in Vue is correct.

Answer (score 6):

From [Official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

> 

- text and textarea elements use **value** property and **input** event;
- checkboxes and radiobuttons use **checked** property and **change** event;
- select fields use **value** as a prop and **change** as an event.

Comment: Have also tried using checked. Didn't change anything.

Comment: selectedLandlords is an array of objects which is being looped by Vue; each of these is a landlord

Comment: Is is_primary prop exists in each item of an array before checking/unchecking?

Comment: It seems that  this.selectedLandlords = this.selectedLandlords.filter(item => { item.is_primary = false; return item}) does not filter items at all, just turns is_primary in each item. Is it intentional?

Comment: Sorry, typo. That was supposed to be map. And yes, is_primary exists on the object before checking/unchecking.

Comment: Doesn't makePrimaryLandlord have to set is_primary for passed 'landord' param?

Comment: Yes, which is why the UI shouldn't be displaying the checkbox as checked. However, it is. The object data says all of these values are false, however the browser displays the boxes as checked.

Comment: thanks! i'm dumb.. wasted 2 hours on this

Answer (score 3):

Use `:input-value` instead of `:value`

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly make it up from your code, but are you sure the property is_primary is available in the objects on load of the viewmodel? So for example this.selectedLandlords.push({ Name:'John', is_primary: false, ...}) should contain the is_primary field to make it reactive.

If not, you should use Vue.set(item, 'is_primary', false) to make it reactive.

Answer (score 0):

try using the `key` attributes to re-render the checkbox.

reference: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/